# R studio blank upon opening (AFTER Win7 update)

Tags: rstudio

I tried different things (reinstalled ... etc)! Is there a special correctional program for this problem? or can I launch Rstudio from RGui(32bit)? or something radical? Thanks! (I'm desperate.)

Comment: I've had a similar issue before. Have you tried adding path to R in Environment Variables?

Comment: I launch with Ctrl-Rstudio (that is set the path to R)

Comment: Tried the official RStudio support services?

Comment: Here is the answer from RStudio.
"We are sorry that we are not able to provide direct support for our open source (free) products but would suggest that you post your issue ... to a site such as stackoverflow.com."

Comment: "I've had a similar issue before. Have you tried adding path to R in Environment Variables? – creativename" --------------
Where this "Environment Variables"?
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I tried different things, including Ctrl-RSstudio: there everything is displayed correctly, but the screen remains to be white and non-functional (System: Win7)